# "Study/Investigate the Possibility": Which One and Why?

Tags: word-choice

I just changed a sentence from "Further, we ***study*** the possibility that ..." to "we ***investigate*** the possibility", and I'm not sure why it seems better that way.

Is it because, in this context, "study" sounds more like "memorize", while "investigate" here carries more a meaning of "examine, look into and/or consider"? Or is it just a case of collocation and common usage? Or, alternatively, am I just mistaken that one is more preferable than the other?

Answer (score 2):

To me, "studying a possibility" doesn't make sense:  the possibility is a simple, binary thing:  it either exists or it doesn't.  When we investigate a possibility, we are trying to find out if it exists or not.  It's a simple yes-no thing.  Once we've answered the yes-no question we can **go on** to study **the thing that there was a possibility of**, but that's not the possibility.

Let's say that I had a theory that there was a link between height and intelligence.  I could say that **there is a possibility of a link between height and intelligence**.  This link is either there or it isn't.  At this stage, I would **investigate the possibility of a link between height and intelligence**, with some statistical studies for example.  I don't know if the link is there so I'm not studying it (despite looking at some "studies") - I'm investigating it.

Later, I might establish that there is a link, and go on to **study the link** - at this stage, I'm **not** studying the possibility - i've gone past that stage by establishing that the link exists.  I'm now studying the link, not the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is some overlap between the two words, I tend to use  ***study*** for school and undergraduate students (the sense being to read up information already produced (by others) about something), and ***investigate*** for projects (and police work) which require active research to push back the boundaries of current knowledge.

It depends what you're wanting to say.

***Study*** -  To think, ponder, and related senses. To think intently; to meditate, reflect; (also) to try to recollect something or come to a decision (OED).

***Investigate*** - To search or inquire into; to examine (a matter) systematically or in detail; to make an inquiry or examination into (OED).